# java int[] val or int val[]

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, integer

I'm new to Java and I know this is a dumb question, but I can't understand the way how Java is initializing his variables. I tried to do some test, but I can't figure out how does this is working.

When I was learning programming C or Java, the syntax of defining a new variable was like this:

```
type name;
int value;
```

and an array of integers:

```
type name[];
int values[];
```

In Java `int[] val;` this would be an array in array?

Ex:

```
int[] val = new int[2];

val[0] = 012345; // Error ?
```

The ex above is correct. So that means the following example is the same?

```
int val[] = new int[2];
val[0] = 123;
val[1] = 456;

int[] val2 = new int[2];
val2[0] = 789;
val2[0] = 101;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between two array declarations in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277889/whats-the-difference-between-two-array-declarations-in-java)

Comment: "In Java, `int[] val;` would be an array in array?"  No.  It's a declaration of a reference to an array of ints.  The actual array of ints is created with the call to `new int[2]`.

Comment: The equivalent notation `int val[]` was introduced because it's familiar to those coming from C.

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129178/difference-between-int-array-and-int-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes `int val[] = new int[2];` does exactly the same as `int[] val2 = new int[2];`.

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2)

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both

So even something like

```
int[] val2[] = new int[2][3]
```

is correct (although unusual) for ***two dimensional*** array.

Comment: @mikera before this question also didn't know about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Both declarations mean the same thing.

```
int val[] = new int[2];
int[] val2 = new int[2];
```

However, you should use the **first** notation. Most programmers consider it more readable.

Comment: I believe you meant to say that most C programmers consider the first form more readable.

Comment: The following are types: `String`, `double`, `List<Long>`, `int[]`. Thus, the array specifier `[]` is part of the _type_, not part of the variable name. You should use the *second* notation. :)

Comment: It's good that we don't have three ways of declaration. Third comment would say that the "new" version is most readable :)